# Does a US citizen need more than an enhanced driver's license to cross back into the US by land?

Tags: regulations

I have relatives coming from Michigan to Texas. They would like to visit Mexico. Will they need more than the enhanced driver's license to get back into the US at Nuevo Progreso?

Comment: Reminder that travellers TO Mexico are required and expected to have a passport (even if they don't ask for it at the border)

Answer (score 2):

An enhanced driver's license is enough to enter the US by land under the [Western Hemisphere Travel Initiative](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/western-hemisphere-travel-initiative).